# Remove elements from session array

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, session

I'm attempting to build a super simple shopping cart using symfony for my learning purposes. Currently I'm using sessions to store 'products' that a user has selected in an array. I have three questions that I want to ask...

1. I want a button that will remove a 'product' from the session array(The user is displayed a list of 'products' selected by them in a table. The user can then choose to remove a 'product' from the table and subsequently removing the 'product' from the session array). I'm a super beginner in jquery, however, I'm sure this can be accomplished using jquery. How can I do this? I researched splice, and remove functions but was unable to get things running. Could someone give me examples using my twig file so I can better understand the correct way to set things up?

cart.twig:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1><u><i>Welcome to the Cart</i></u></h1>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price Per Unit</th>
                    <th>Remove From Cart</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {% for key, cartValue in cartArray %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ cartValue[0] }}</td> <!--Product-->
                        <td>{{ cartValue[1] }}</td> <!--Quantity-->
                        <td>${{ cartValue[2] }}</td> <!--Price Per Unit-->
                        <td> <script type="text/javascript"> 
                                $(function() {(
                                    cartArray.splice(cartArray.indexOf(0),1);
                                )};
                            </script>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}    
            </tbody>
        </table> <!--top table-->

            <div class="money-container">
                <p class="text-right">Total Cost: ${{ totalCostOfAllProducts }}</p>
            </div><!--moneyContainer-->

    </div> <!--container-->

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('product_bought', {'id': entity.id }) }}">
                        Buy These Products
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('product') }}">
                        Add More Products
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('product_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
            </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

2. Again from more research I keep seeing that data manipulation should remain in the controller class. Would doing the above break that rule? If so, how should I go about accomplishing my task in my controller?

ProductController:

```
namespace PaT\ShopTestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use PaT\ShopTestBundle\Entity\Product;
use PaT\ShopTestBundle\Form\ProductType;

/**
 * Product controller.
 *
 * @Route("/product")
 */
class ProductController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Product entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="product")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //$entities = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->findAll();

        $categories = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Category')->findAll();

        return array(
            'categories' => $categories,
           //'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="product_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("PaTShopTestBundle:Product:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Product();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Product entity.
     *
     * @param Product $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Product $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('product_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="product_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Product();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="product_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
        } else {
            //dump($entity); die;
            $descriptions = $entity->getDescriptions();
            //dump($entity); die;
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'descriptions'=> $descriptions,
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="product_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Product entity.
    *
    * @param Product $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Product $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('product_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="product_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("PaTShopTestBundle:Product:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="product_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Product entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('product_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }

    /** 
     * Creates the option to 'add product to cart'.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/cart", name="product_cart")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function cartAction(Request $request, $id) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

        $session = $request->getSession(); //session----------------

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0;

        $cartArray = array();

        if (is_null($cartArray) || !$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error: Nothin in Array/Entity');
        } else {
            $cartArray = $session->get('cartArray', []);

            $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = [$entity->getName(), $entity->getQuantity(), $entity->getPrice()];

            foreach ($cartArray as $key => $product) {
                    // dump($cartArray); die;
                    // dump($key); die;
                    $productEntity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($key);
                    $quantity = $productEntity->getQuantity();
                    $price = $productEntity->getPrice();
                    $totalCostOfAllProducts += $price * $quantity;
            }
        }

        //$remove = unset($cartArray);

        // if (isset($_POST['Button'])) {
        //     unset($cartArray[1]); //remove index
        // }

        //above did nothing

        $session->set('cartArray', $cartArray); //session---------------

        //var_dump($cartArray); die;

        return array(
            'price'     => $price,
            'quantity'  => $quantity,
            'totalCostOfAllProducts'   => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
            'cartArray'   => $cartArray,
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays the products bought from products 'added to cart'
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/bought", name="product_bought")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function boughtAction(Request $request, $id) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);

        $session = $request->getSession(); //session----------------

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        $totalCostOfAllProducts = 0;

        $cartArray = array();

        if (is_null($cartArray) || !$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error: Nothing Found In Entity/Array');
        } else {
            $cartArray = $session->get('cartArray', []);

            $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = [$entity->getName()];

            foreach ($cartArray as $key => $value) {
                $prodEnt = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($key);
                $quantity = $prodEnt->getQuantity();
                $price = $prodEnt->getPrice();
                $totalCostOfAllProducts += $price * $quantity;
            }
        }

        $session->set('cartArray', $cartArray); //session---------------
        $request->getSession()->invalidate(1);

        return array(
            'price'     => $price,
            'quantity'  => $quantity,
            'totalCostOfAllProducts' => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
            'cartArray' => $cartArray,
        );
    }
}
```

3. Finally, How can I do all of this WITHOUT using a session array logic like I'm doing now. People I've talked to have told me relying on sessions to create an array is bad practice. What's the better way to do what I'm doing. (If this last question is too broad or opinion based then either ignore it or leave some links/quick answers to help answer but please don't close this whole thing based on this one)

Any help is really appreciated, Thanks!!

EDIT: dump array:

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Water"
    1 => 5
    2 => 2.75
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Rooster"
    1 => 1
    2 => 105.0
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Apple Sauce"
    1 => 1
    2 => 9.25
  ]
]
```

Also here is my newest attempt: (still doing nothing/not working)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#removeButton').click(function() {
        cartArray.splice(indexOf(($this), 1);
    });
</script>
```

(Since the quantity of 'products' can be more than 1, the second argument in splice may not work. So splice may not be the answer I need...Or not, I'm totally guessing here

Comment: Can the product show up more than once in the array or not?

Comment: No it cannot show up more than once

Comment: Well you said .splice does not work, the first parameter in splice is the starting index where you want to remove elements, the second parameter is how many items you want to remove.  you should be using `array.splice(indexOf("someValueInArray"), 1)` The `indexOf("value")` will return the index of that value in the array. The second will delete only 1 entry from that starting index..

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, ''someValueInArray" would be the index that I want to delete from? correct?

Comment: no it is the value in the array not an index. For instance the "food" product `["food", "soap", ect...]`, indexOf("food") will return the index of where food is in the array so it will return 0

Comment: So like how @rubes114 said, I should use $this to reference the element relative to which 'product' I want to remove. So this would go in the "someValueInArray" position...correct?

Comment: Lets say this is your product array `["apple", "orange", "beef"]` it will look like this `cartArray.splice(cartArray.indexOf("apple"),1);` that will make the array look like `["orange", "beef"]`

Comment: Yes create the event and attach it to the button to "remove" a product, do not use `$(this).parent.parent`, just give the button an id `$('#mybutton').click(function(){//code here})`

Comment: I think I'm getting confused because this is what my array looks like, What would be the "someValueOfIndex" here? if you tell me this, I'll leave you alone haha sorry for being repetitive. array:3 [1 => array:3 [0 => "Water" 1 => 5 2 => 2.75] 5 => array:3 [0 => "Rooster" 1 => 1 2 => 105.0] 4 => array:3 [0 => "Pencil" 1 => 2 2 => 5.5] ] Sorry I don't know how to format this correctly here

Comment: use this character to format it ` surround your text with it, it is underneath the `esc` key on the keyboard, thats too hard to read. Also is that php?

Comment: I made an edit to the question to include the dump, it's much easier to look at there

Comment: `$this` does not represent the value in your array. That's why it does not work. Do a `console.log($this)` and see what the value is.

Comment: it looks like you have an array of arrays try `cartArray.splice(cartArray[0][0].indexOf("water"),1);` I am not familiar with that syntax, I just through a wild guess try to console.log that code and see what the value is.

Comment: I keep getting, cartArray is not defined in console...as far as my knowledge of it goes, it is

Comment: the last piece of code you have in the script tag for your edit does not work, you can't just use `cartarray` anywhere you want, you have to figure out how to get the array first.

Comment: if I feed cartArray in the function argument, does that get cartArray? the error did go away but I'm not sure if it's the same cartArray...

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP where in your `deleteAction` function are you grabbing the array? Your remove function is commented out., Post all of your code in JS fiddle so I can dink around with it.

Comment: I realized my issues with this problem. It does break the rule about data manipulation. Plus using jquery for this is kinda counter intuitive because I would still need to interact with the server. I decided to just make another Action function to handle removing things from the array. Thanks for all your help though! very much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the query target for your function and this will be the button if I understand you right. Give your button an id and reference that in the tag as such `$( '#buttonid' ).click( function(){ #your code here })` Also jquery has a `$(this)` selector which allows to you to reference an element relative to the current context of what triggered the action. So in your case `$(this).parent().parent()` would refer to the `<tr>` containing the button that was clicked. Also for what it's worth you should probably put the script at the top or bottom of the page